# Is there a db pattern where the incoming items set the new db state (i.e. add & remove) but exisitng items remain untouched?

Tags: javascript, typescript, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am having a moment of database verbage overload, and I'm not sure if folks have seen this pattern before or if there might be a better way:

tl;dr Is there a database pattern where the incoming items completely set the new db (i.e. items are added & removed) but all exisitng items remain untouched?

I am in the process of extending functionality to a database service which in the past has the behavior of setting the db to reflect incoming items. It currently does not allow for updating any of the items because all it does is calculate items to add, to remove, and to ignore. What this looks like in practice is that if we have arrays of `incoming` items and already `existing` items in the db we calculate the following:

```
incoming = [1,2,3]
existing = [3,4,5]
```

gives ->

```
desiredItems = [3,4,5]
toAdd = [4,5]
toRemove = [1,2]
toIgnore = [3]
```

My understanding is that this provides a fairly simple db transaction list we can calculate & use without having to hit the DB for any already existing items. For all intents and purposes the first "set" behavior must remain, so my solution is to extend this functionality by switching on a variable (perhaps `set` and `upsert`?).

I would really like to add functionality to be able to "upsert" the items so given the same incoming and existing arrays instead gives:

```
desiredItems = [1,2,3,4,5]
toAdd = [4,5]
toRemove = []
toUpdate = [3]
toIgnore = [1,2]
```

In this case I would be adding a `toUpdate` array which could be populated in the "upsert" flow, but would never be populated in the "set" flow, and the `toRemove` array would always be empty in the "upsert" flow and could be populated in the "set" flow. This would result in a db transation list which would still include the items to add, remove (always emtpy in this flow), and now to update while still leaving out items to ignore.

If I am correct about my "upsert flow" being a true "upsert" what the heck would the first pattern be called? I can't even figure out the verbage to do more research on it.

---

I have this pattern working correctly to where I can get all of the correct values for desired, toAdd, toRemove, toUpdate, and toIgore for both the "set" and "update" states, but this seems to be an incredbily messy and gnarly way to go about this.

Comment: This key requirement is ambiguous: "the incoming items completely set the new db (i.e. items are added & removed) but all exisitng items remain untouched", to me at least.

Comment: Yes, I'm certainly having trouble defining it clearly (which is my main problem...)

The best way I can describe it is: if the incoming items are [3,4,5] and the existing db items are [1,2,3], the resulting (or desired) state of the items in the db will be [3,4,5], where [1,2] will be deleted, [3] will be ignored, and [4,5] will be added

So the incoming set of items [3,4,5] will completely determine the end state of the database, where any new items are added, any missing items are removed, and any existing items are ignored.

Comment: That's a very unusual requirement. So the client submits a batch of items [3,4,5] against a table containing [1,2,3] and that should trigger a sequence of operations that deletes [1,2], inserts [4,5], and leaves [3] alone.  You'd have to do this client-side. Is there any reason you can't build this (unusual) logic into your client when it submits a batch of items? Also, how would you expect multiple clients submitting a batch each at the same time to deal with the potential consistency issues? Maybe you can explain the actual use case here.